# How to compare two dataframes and select the next and second next row after matching the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this signal dataframe:

```
       Date      M   SH    SM
0 2023-06-16     0    1     0
1 2023-06-21    59    0     0
2 2023-07-07    74    0     0
3 2023-05-31     0    0     1
4 2023-06-13    39    0     0
5 2023-07-07     0    1     0
```

And the calendar df:

```
0    2024-01-03
1    2023-12-28
2    2023-12-25
3    2023-12-20
4    2023-12-15
5    2023-12-12
6    2023-12-07
7    2023-12-04
8    2023-11-29
9    2023-11-24
10   2023-11-21
11   2023-11-16
12   2023-11-13
13   2023-11-08
14   2023-11-03
15   2023-10-31
16   2023-10-26
17   2023-10-23
18   2023-10-18
19   2023-10-13
20   2023-10-05
21   2023-10-02
22   2023-09-27
23   2023-09-22
24   2023-09-19
25   2023-09-14
26   2023-09-11
27   2023-09-06
28   2023-09-01
29   2023-08-28
30   2023-08-23
31   2023-08-18
32   2023-08-15
33   2023-08-10
34   2023-08-07
35   2023-08-02
36   2023-07-28
37   2023-07-25
38   2023-07-20
39   2023-07-17
40   2023-07-12
41   2023-07-07
42   2023-07-04
43   2023-06-26
44   2023-06-21
45   2023-06-16
46   2023-06-13
47   2023-06-08
```

The task is to create ['Effective'] and ['Until'] columns for the signal dataframe. Where effective date is the next date and until date is the second next date from the calendar df.
For instance for date 2023-07-07 Effective date should be 2023-07-12 and Until date should be 2023-07-17.

```
        Date     M   SH    SM    Effective        Until
5 2023-07-07     0    1     0   2023-07-12   2023-07-17
```

To select the dates for a single date I used something like:

```
effective = df3.loc[df3.isin(['2023-07-07'])].index[0]-1
until = df3.loc[df3.isin(['2023-07-07'])].index[0]-2

effective = df3.iloc[effective]
until = df3.iloc[until]
```

However I'm not sure how to select corresponding indexes with a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a join, i.e., `pd.merge`. Your first data frame is `df1`, the second one `df2`. The columns of `df2` are called `id` and `Date`. Firstly, create the two columns `Effective` and `Until` in `df2` by using `shift`.

```
df2['Effective'] = df2['Date'].shift(1)
df2['Until'] = df2['Date'].shift(2)
```

Then merge the two data frames (by the same named column `Date`, and drop the not needed `id` column in `df2`).

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2.drop('id', axis=1), how='left')
```

Result:

```
print(df3)

         Date   M  SH  SM   Effective       Until
0  2023-06-16   0   1   0  2023-06-21  2023-06-26
1  2023-06-21  59   0   0  2023-06-26  2023-07-04
2  2023-07-07  74   0   0  2023-07-12  2023-07-17
3  2023-05-31   0   0   1         NaN         NaN
4  2023-06-13  39   0   0  2023-06-16  2023-06-21
5  2023-07-07   0   1   0  2023-07-12  2023-07-17
```